# SQL query CASE with the result in a new column

Tags: sql

I have this values from a table Sales

**Sales**

- Days old of purchase
- Mount of purchase

Whith the case or another function, i want to do a operation and separate the result based on the days of old, i dont need to add the columns to the table, just add the column at the result of the query.

**Result of query**

- Days old of the purchase
- Mount of the purchase
- mount of the purchase made between 1 and 15 days
- mount of the puchase made between 16 and 30 days
  .....

Thanks

Comment: Needs more information and some sample code, tables, data etc.

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.  And, tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you've written, here is what I would try:

```
SELECT
    DaysOld,
    Amount, --assuming you meant 'amount' when you said 'mount'
    CASE
        WHEN DaysOld > 0 AND DaysOld <= 15 THEN Amount
        ELSE 0
    END AS Amount1to15,
    CASE
        WHEN DaysOld > 15 AND DaysOld <= 31 THEN Amount
        ELSE 0
    END AS Amount16to31 --added to include months w/ 31 days
FROM Sales
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what i was looking for... thank you very much for your help.